# Is there a way to UV unwrap each island separately in blender?

Tags: uv

this is what I mean by each island, right now I have to select-linked by seams but it would be easier if every island could be unwrapped. I know this is not usual to do.

[image]

Comment: Could clarify exactly what you're trying to do? Are you saying you want it to where when you unwrap, all the islands pile on each other?

Comment: yeah, all islands have to be UV unwrapped as If I selected a portion of the mesh and then UV unwrap, that would lead to all the islands to pile each one another. But I don't know if you could do that with the UV editor or some addon on blender, like an option for "stretch islands to all UV space" or something like that